# Conceptual question about casting objects using wildcard generics

Tags: java, generics, casting, compiler-errors, wildcard

I am trying to understand why the compiler treats objects (using wildcard generics) being inline declared differently then objects being first set to an variable.

See the following example:

```java
public class SillyTest{

    interface A<T extends B> {}
    interface B {}

    @Test
    public void m() {

        Class<?> b1 = A.class.getClass();
        Class<? extends B> bb1 = (Class<? extends B>) b1; // works fine

        Class<? extends B> bb2 = (Class<? extends B>) A.class.getClass(); // doesn't compile
        Class<? extends B> bb3 = (Class<? extends B>)(A.class.getClass()); // also doesn't compile
    }
}
```

**Note: Depending on your compiler configuration you may have to add an `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` Annotation.**

Why does the compiler handles these two cases different? I would expect that due to compiler inlining these calls should be equivalent anyway. Apart from the fact that this is an uncheckted cast (which may or may not work) `getClass()` returns an `Class<?>`, so I do not see a reason why this should be handled differently.

Comment: you can see this discussion it may help : https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/generic-type-cast-involving-wildcard-type.692846/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Class<A>` doesn't extend `B`, your two last statements are obviously false, and that can be determined at compile time. `b1` on the other hand, is of type `Class<?>`, so it is not known at compile time whether `?` does extends B or not. There needs to be a runtime check.